# Add different static colors for sliderbar in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to shiny. I would like to give static color for the slider bar irrespective of the range selected in shiny dashboard. I want to have different color for slider as follows, Ex: 0 to 40 – red, 40 to 60 – blue, 60 to 100 – green. 
Please help me solve this issue.
My code,

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),

                  dashboardSidebar(
                    sidebarMenu(
                      menuItem("Complete", tabName = "comp"))),

                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "comp",
                          fluidRow(
                              sliderInput("range_var", "", value = c(90,100), min = 0, max = 100, width = '200%'))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  observe({
    updateSliderInput(session, "range_var", label = "", value = c(90, 100), min = 0, max = 100)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks
Balaji

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, then i misinterpreted your question. You can achieve this also by using css-commands and correct selectors:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Complete", tabName = "comp"))),
                    dashboardBody(
                      inlineCSS(".irs-line-left { background-color: red; width: 40%;}
                                 .irs-line-mid { background-color: blue; width: 20%; left: 40%;}
                                 .irs-line-right { background-color: green; width: 40%; left: 60%;}
                                "
                                ),

                      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "comp",
                                fluidRow(
                                  sliderInput("range_var", "", value = c(90,100), min = 0, max = 100, width = '200%'))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out this package - **shinyFeedback** ?

You can see some examples [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyFeedback/vignettes/shinyFeedback-intro.html).

To use multiple feedbacks, you should write all the conditions in one observeEvent - although I didnt manage to make multiple feedbacks working.

Here is the code example from that page for multiple feedbacks:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(), # include shinyFeedback

  numericInput(
    "multiFeedbacks",
    "1 is scary 2 is dangerous", 
    value = 1
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$multiFeedbacks, {
    feedbackWarning(
      inputId = "multiFeedbacks",
      condition = input$multiFeedbacks >= 1,
      text = "Warning 1 is a lonely number"
    )
    feedbackDanger(
      inputId = "multiFeedbacks",
      condition = input$multiFeedbacks >= 2,
      text = "2+ is danger"
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another option would be to use the **shinyjs** package, where you can run java-script and send css-code to the browser. You have to put useShinyjs() in the dashboardBody. The class "irs-bar" is used for all sliders in shiny, so if you want the behaviour only on a certain slider you would have to adapt the css selector (.irs-bar). (See next example).
Here is a little example oh how you could achieve the desired behaviour:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Complete", tabName = "comp"))),
                    dashboardBody(
                      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "comp",
                                fluidRow(
                                  sliderInput("range_var", "", value = c(90,100), min = 0, max = 100, width = '200%'))))))

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  observeEvent(input$range_var, {
    if (input$range_var[1] <= 40) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".irs-bar").css("background-color"," red")'))
    }
    if (input$range_var[1] > 40 & input$range_var[1] < 60) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".irs-bar").css("background-color"," blue")'))
    }
    if (input$range_var[1] > 60 & input$range_var[1] < 100) {
      runjs(paste0('$(".irs-bar").css("background-color"," green")'))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The following example shows how to style only one specific sliderInput. The sliderInputs are put in 2 divs with ids. In the runjs function the css selector is adapted to only style the first sliderInput.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black",
                    dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Complete", tabName = "comp"))),
                    dashboardBody(
                      shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem(tabName = "comp",
                                fluidRow(
                                  div(id="range_var_css",
                                    sliderInput("range_var", "", value = c(90,100), min = 0, max = 100, width = '200%')
                                    ),
                                  div(id="range_var_css1",
                                    sliderInput("range_var1", "", value = c(90,100), min = 0, max = 100, width = '200%')
                                    )

                                  ))))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  observeEvent(input$range_var, {
    if (input$range_var[1] <= 40) {
      runjs(paste0('$("#range_var_css .irs-bar").css("background-color"," red")'))
    }
    if (input$range_var[1] > 40 & input$range_var[1] < 60) {
      runjs(paste0('$("#range_var_css .irs-bar").css("background-color"," blue")'))
    }
    if (input$range_var[1] > 60 & input$range_var[1] < 100) {
      runjs(paste0('$("#range_var_css .irs-bar").css("background-color"," green")'))
    }
  })
}
```

To fully style the sliderInput to your desired color, you also have to change the css of the border-bottom and border-top of the slider, to something like that:

```
    if (input$range_var[1] <= 40) {
      runjs(paste0('$("#range_var_css .irs-bar").css({
"background-color": "red", 
"border-top": "1px solid red", 
"border-bottom": "1px solid red"})'))
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the effort and solution. But it doesn't meet my requirement. Your solution changes color based on range selected in slider bar, but i want color to be static, like (for 0 to 20 - red, 20 to 80 - blue,etc). Instead of plain slider bar, i want colored slider bar